# Send Value Raw Transaction fails with insufficient funds for gas

Tags: web3js, ether

```
        const amount = web3.utils.toWei("0.0000001", "ether");
        var gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
        var gasLimit = 21000;

        var nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(process.env.ETH_ADDRESS);
        var rawTransaction = {
          "from": process.env.ETH_ADDRESS,
          "nonce": web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
          "gasPrice": web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice),
          "gasLimit": web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit),
          "to": transferRequest.walletAddress,
          "value": web3.utils.toHex(amount),
          "chainId": 5 // Remember to change this
        };
        const serializedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawTransaction,process.env.ETH_SECRET);
        const txid = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(serializedTx.rawTransaction);
```

raise error

```
err: insufficient funds for gas * price + value: address myAddress have 23560572337336344 want 15223021483094632145177583472 (supplied gas 21000)
```

I have 0.0236 ETH in my wallet. But why can’t I send even a very small amount of ETH?
I can also send All ETH except fees by Send using the MetaMask GUI.
I tried changing the gas limit value and gas price value, but the error continues to occur.